# Is there any way to do this with a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have no problem getting the `$scope` function referenced in the directive attribute to run. The problem is I need to capture the element that was touched in the directive and pass it to the function in the attribute. I haven't figure out how to do that. Isolating the scope in the directives will throw an error because there's 2 directives trying to act on the same element.

With the below code I am getting `$event` as `undefined` and an error of course. Any way to achieve what I want? Or maybe there's a better way?

```
<li class="list-group-item row" data-touchstart="darkenBackground($event)" data-touchend="lightenBackground($event)">
```

..

```
angular.module('myNotes')
    .directive('touchstart', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.bind('touchstart', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    scope.$apply(attrs.touchstart);
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

angular.module('myNotes')
    .controller('notesCtrl', ['$scope', 'Site',
        function($scope, Site) {
            Site.setTitle('My Notes');
            Site.setActiveNavLink('myNotes');

            $scope.darkenBackground = function($event) {
                angular.element($event.currentTarget)
                    .css('background-color', '#eee');
            };
            $scope.lightenBackground = function($event) {
                angular.element($event.currentTarget)
                    .css('background-color', '#fff');
            }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the issue:

```
scope.$apply(attrs.touchstart);
```

When you call `scope.$apply` directly on an angular expression (which is what `attrs.touchstart` is), it will automatically evaluate that expression against `scope`, so `scope.$event` (which is undefined) is passed to the callback.

To pass the event to the callback, you can use the second parameter (called "locals") of `scope.$eval` to temporarily include an `$event` property on the scope while evaluating the expression.

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.bind('touchstart', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.$eval(attrs.touchstart, {$event: e});
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I like this answer better than mine because I am not required to isolate the scope.  This way I can also use separate directives for touchstart and touchend.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like so, but I'm not sure if it's the best/proper approach:

```
<li class="list-group-item row" data-touchstart="darkenBackground(event)">
```

...

```
angular.module('myNotes')
    .directive('touchstart', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                touchstart: '&'
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.bind('touchstart', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    scope.$apply(scope.touchstart({event: e}));
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

angular.module('myNotes')
    .controller('notesCtrl', ['$scope', 'Site',
        function($scope, Site) {
            Site.setTitle('My Notes');
            Site.setActiveNavLink('myNotes');

            $scope.darkenBackground = function(event) {
                var elem = angular.element(event.currentTarget);

                elem.css('background-color', '#eee');
                elem.bind('touchend', function (e) {
                    $scope.lightenBackground(e);
                })
            };
            $scope.lightenBackground = function(event) {
                angular.element(event.currentTarget)
                    .css('background-color', '#fff');
            };
    }]);
```

Comment: This works too, assuming an isolate scope meets your needs, but you should wrap the call to `scope.touchstart` using `scope.$apply`, and the same thing anytime you do angular-related things outside of angular, such as inside of a DOM event callback.

Comment: @mzulch Ah yes! I had meant to do that and forgot to add it after the whole troubleshooting phase.  I updated my answer.